# Wordpress is not showing number of comments per post

Tags: php, wordpress

so im trying to make wordpress loop with nubmer of comments show per post. I just want posts from one category. Loop is working, but number of comments are not correct. On every single post it just say that there is no comments (even when i have 10 or more commentes there)

```
<?php
                $query = new WP_Query('category_name=blog&post_type=post');
                if ($query->have_posts()) :
                    ?>
                <?php
                    // Start the loop.
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 blog_single_homepage">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row align-items-end">
                                <div class="col-5 col-md-3 autor_section">

                                   <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), '150', $default, $alt, array( 'class' => array( 'rounded-circle' ) ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-7 col-md-9 autor_info">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>" class="autor_name"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
                                    <span class="align-middle"><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
                                    <div class="cat">
                                        <p><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 blog_content_short">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 50); ?></p>
                                <div class="read_more_over">
                                    <div class="title_inner">
                                        <?php the_title() ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner_show">
                                        Read more
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="comments">
                                <?php 
printf( _nx( 'One Comment', '%1$s Comments', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'textdomain' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );

?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    // End the loop.
                endwhile;
                else :
                    echo 'No blog posts...';

                endif;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly. Please verify that the comments are approved. This code doesn't show the comments that are not approved yet. If you want details of ALL the comments, use `wp_count_comments`. This returns details of comments on every status: See more details here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/SWbW1 :S i have over 400+ approved comments :S i just dont get it

Comment: `$comments_count = wp_count_comments(); var_dump($comments_count);` Can you try adding that before `printf( _nx...` line on your code.

Comment: object(stdClass)#1237 (7) { ["approved"]=> string(3) "403" ["spam"]=> int(0) ["trash"]=> int(0) ["post-trashed"]=> int(0) ["total_comments"]=> int(415) ["all"]=> int(415) ["moderated"]=> string(2) "12" } 0 Comments

Comment: so if you now do `$comments_count->approved` you should get your count which is 403.